# Trouble loading data into Snowflake using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to import a small table of data from Azure SQL into Snowflake using Azure Data Factory.

Normally I do not have any issues using this approach:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#staged-copy-to-snowflake

But now I have an issue, with a source table that looks like this:
[image]
There is two columns `SLA_Processing_start_time` and `SLA_Processing_end_time` that have the datatype `TIME`

Somehow, while writing the data to the staged area, the data is changed to something like `0:08:00:00.0000000,0:17:00:00.0000000` and that causes for an error like:

`Time '0:08:00:00.0000000' is not recognized File`

The mapping looks like this:
[image]

I have tried adding a `TIME_FORMAT` property like `'HH24:MI:SS.FF'` but that did not help.
Any ideas to why `08:00:00` becomes `0:08:00:00.0000000` and how to avoid it?

Comment: Can you show what you have in the Mapping tab? What type is the column on the Snowflake side?

Comment: I actually have been thinking perhaps the precision on the time columns (default TIME(9)) is to high, and that might be the issue.

Comment: Are you able to use functions to convert the source time? You could use [to_time](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_time.html) to match the format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to recreate your case in my environment.
I have the same error, a leading zero appears ahead of time (**0:** 08:00:00.0000000).
I even grabbed the files it creates on BlobStorage and the zeros are already there.
This activity creates CSV text files without any error handling (double quotes, escape characters etc.).
And on the Snowflake side, it creates a temporary Stage and loads these files.
Unfortunately, it does not clean up after itself and leaves empty directories on BlobStorage. Additionally, you can't use ADLS Gen2. :(

This connector in ADF is not very good, I even had problems to use it for AWS environment, I had to set up a Snowflake account in Azure.
I've tried a few workarounds, and it seems you have two options:

1. **Simple** solution:

   Change the data type on both sides to DateTime and then transform this attribute on the Snowflake side. If you cannot change the type on the source side, you can just use the "query" option and write SELECT using the CAST / CONVERT function.
2. **Recommended** solution:

   - Use the Copy data activity to insert your data on BlobStorage / ADLS (this activity did it anyway) preferably in the parquet file format and a self-designed structure ([Best practices for using Azure Data Lake Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-best-practices)).
   - Create a permanent Snowflake Stage for your BlobStorage / ADLS.
   - Add a Lookup activity and do the loading of data into a table from files there, you can use a regular query or write a stored procedure and call it.

   Thanks to this, you will have more control over what is happening and you will build a DataLake solution for your organization.

   [image]

Comment: Hi Michael,
I've marked you answer (currently the only one) as the solution, as it came close to my own workaround. To me, it seems there is a bug, in the built-in direct copy to Snowflake feature, and since I could not figure out how to control that intermediate blob format, I ended up doing that step manually.

Comment: Thank you, please consider my solution, it is much cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is pretty close to the accepted answer, but I still believe that there is a bug in the build-in direct to Snowflake copy feature.

Since I could not figure out, how to control that intermediate blob file, that is created on a direct to Snowflake copy, I ended up writing a plain file into the blob storage, and reading it again, to load into Snowflake

[image]

So instead having it all in one step, I manually split it up in two actions

One action that takes the data from the AzureSQL and saves it as a plain text file on the blob storage

[image]

And then the second action, that reads the file, and loads it into Snowflake.

This works, and is supposed to be basically the same thing the direct copy to Snowflake does, hence the bug assumption.

Comment: It seems to me that the error is with the ADF connector.
There will be a performance problem in this solution.
We send data to BlobStorage twice and there is a risk of errors, plus unnecessary conversion.